# How to enable hot-sync in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, myeclipse

I have a web project(maven) and this project has many dependencies as jar files(downloaded from maven repository) and two projects in my work space. recently I have changed my IDE from My Eclipse to Eclipse. In My Eclipse, when I try to deploy the root project into tomcat, that two dependency project classes are deploying in folder /WEB-INF/classes. But in eclipse these two projects are deploying as jar files in /WEB-INF/lib. As far as I know this because of this configuration on deployment assembly in My Eclipse:

[image]

But the corresponding configuration in eclipse is something like this:

[image]

Personally, I think the difference is between the two options bellow deployment assembly in My Eclipse, regarding merged deployment of modules. What kind of changes do I have to apply on eclipse to work same as My Eclipse for deployment?
Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with eclipse. However, [this topic](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/887510/) mentions a kind of simulation of that but doesn't physically deploy the projects, instead using the project output folders. Check it out.